# specman issue with parsing quotation marks

Tags: specman

I am trying to import a string from the unix shell to the program space of specman.
The string i want to import contains quotation marks ("") - for example "hi".
in these cases, the string is not parsed properly . for example
suppose i want to 'echo' some string with quotation marks, i would do the following:

```
 %> echo echo \"\"hi\"\"
```

will output

```
""hi""
```

but if i use the following program, written in e:

```
<'
extend sys {
     run() is also{  
    print output_from("echo \"\"hi\"\"");
    stop_run();
             };
     };
'>
```

i get the following output:

```
 output_from("echo \"\"hi\"\"") = 
 0.      "hi"
```

as you can see - quotation marks are gone. the ones that we see here are coming from the default printing of list values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the `output_from` action, but I assume it treats the input string as a shell command.

By writing `"echo \"\"hi\"\""` what you will essentially get is a string containing `echo ""hi""`. This is because the `\` will be "eaten up" (it's an escape character in `e` as well). The resulting string is what will be executed, which if you try in the shell will also output the same thing. Try adding an escaped `\` as well. I don't have the possibility to start Specman anytime soon so you'll have to try it out.

To test my hypothesis:

```
// just to see what happens with your original string
var some_string : string = "echo \"\"hi\"\"";
print some_string;  // should output    echo ""hi""
```

To try out my solution do something like this:

```
// might need to fiddle with the escaping here
var some_other_string : string = "echo \\\"\\\"hi\\\"\\\"";
print some_other_string;  // should output    echo \"\"hi\"\"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing your string through multiple string interpreters.  First Specman's, then your shell's string interpreter.

You can debug getting your string through Specman's interpreter first by printing out command you want to pass to the shell first

```
message(None,"echo [...]")`
```

Once the printed command looks like it would when you execute it on the shell, then it is ready to be put into `output_from` command.  You can build up the shell command using normal Specman string manipulation functions.